# How to format output of a select statement in Postgres back into a delimited file?

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am trying to work with some oddly created 'dumps' of some tables in postgres. Due to the tables containing specific data I will have to refrain from posting the exact information but I can give an example.

To give a bit more information, someone though that this exact command was a good way to backup a table.

```
echo 'select * from test1'|psql > test1.date.txt
```

However, in this one example that gives a lot of information that no one neeeds. To also be even more fun the person saw fit to remove the | that is normally seen with the data.

So what I end up with is something like this.

```
rowid            test1
-------+----------------------
     1     hi
     2     no
(2 rows)
```

To also note, for this customer there are multiple tables here. My thoughts here was to use some simple python to figure out where in each line the + was and then mark those points. Then apply those points to each line throughout the file.

I was able to make this work for one set of files but for some reason the next set of files just doesn't work. What happens instead is that on most lines a pipe gets thrown in the middle of data

Maybe there is something I missing here, but does anyone see an easy way to put something like the above back into a normal delimiter file that I could then just load into the database?

Any python or bash related suggestions would also work in this case. Thank you.

Comment: If you have less that 10,000 or so fields, you can read each line into an array (though quoting and fields with spaces may be a problem). If your actual data has whitespace before the start of the data, and the headings all start with a non-empty char, that gives you a simple way to skip the headings. Or if headings are always 2 rows, just `tail -n+3 file` to get the data. Without an example of a dataset giving you problems, all we can do is guess. The 2-row example above is trivial.

Comment: Use `psql -F ";" -A ` to get unaligned , semicolon-separated output. Use `psql --help` for more info

Comment: When you look at lines causing problems - do you see misaligned data? If no, then show us your code for checking. Also, check if there are no binary/special characters in the dump files causing misalignment.  If yes - your method of using the position of '+' in the second line is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple methods the only way I could make this work sadly was to just use the import feature for Excel and then play with that to get the columns I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, without a real example of where the `'|'` are that are causing problems, or a real example of where you are having problem, it is hard to know whether we are addressing your actual issue. That said, your two primary swiss-army=knives for text processing are `sed` and `awk`. If you have data similar to your example, with pipes between data fields you need to discard, then `awk` provides a fairly easy solution.

Take for example your short example and add a pipe in the middle that needs to be discarded, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/pgsql2.txt
rowid            test1
-------+----------------------
     1  |  hi
     2  |  no
```

To process the file in `awk` discarding the `'|'` and outputting the remaining records in comma-separated-value format, you could do something like the following:

```
awk '{  
    if (NR > 2) { 
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            if ($i != "|") {
                if (i == 1)
                    printf "%s", $i
                else
                    printf ",%s", $i
            }
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
}' inputfile
```

Which simply reads from `inputfile` (last line) and loops over the number of fields (`NF`) (3 in this case) and if the row-number is `> 2` (to omit the heading) and the field `$i` is not `"|"`, then it simply checks if this is the first field and outputs it without a comma, otherwise all other fields are output with a preceding comma.

**Example Output**

```
1,hi
2,no
```

`awk` is a bit awkward at first, but as far as text processing goes, there isn't much that will top it.